# Have .htaccess ask for password depending on domain name

Tags: .htaccess, dns

We have several domain name aliases all pointing to the same server and directory (just aliases).

But I'd like to password-protect (htaccess) the site when people come from certain domain names.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using [`SetEnvIf`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif) and [`<IfDefine>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#ifdefine):

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Host ^www\.example\.com$ host_a
SetEnvIfNoCase Host ^www\.example\.org$ host_b
SetEnvIfNoCase Host ^www\.example\.net$ host_c

<IfDefine host_a>
    …
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine host_b>
    …
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine host_c>
    …
</IfDefine>
```

Comment: Sweet. Just what I was looking for.